# UnsatisfiedLinkError while executing new Mat()

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans

i am currently trying to code a little program to take picture of newly students and save them by their names etc to ease the inscriptions things etc.

So here is my problem, i found a great tutorial to help me using a webcam:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/717283/How-to-use-OpenCV-with-Java-under-NetBeans-IDE

I can run this project with no error but when i try to import some code to mine i got this error:

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()J
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:24)
    at recupphoto.Ihm.<init>(Ihm.java:38)
    at recupphoto.RecupPhoto.main(RecupPhoto.java:19)
Java Result: 1
```

The error occurs when i execute theses lines:

```html
Mat frame = new Mat();
MatOfByte mem = new MatOfByte();
```

Here are my imports in case it could help to find out:

```html
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;
```

While compilation i got this message, dunno if related or so

Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Both error appears (i guess) when Mat() is called but i cannot find how to fix this.

I should really use some helps or tips here! Thanks for reading this and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: This sort of error indicates that a dynamically loadable library (part of the native code that lies behind OpenCV's Java API) is missing, perhaps it's not in the library loading path or the like. You should review your installation setup.

Comment: What do u mean by installation setup? I'm quite beginner.

Comment: I mean - where you placed the OpenCV libraries, whether you followed all the setup steps in the OpenCV installation procedure properly. Whether you ran NetBeans fresh after you completed installation of OpenCV. And you should also indicate what operating system and version you are running, given that this is a Native code issue.

Comment: What files are in that Library folder?

Comment: I ran the OpenCv extractor at C:\OpenCv and get no error message so i guess the whole thing was done properly
i'm using:
w8.1 pro,
NetBeans IDE 8.0.2,
OpenCv300

Comment: At C:\opencv\build\java i got opencv-300.jar (which contains all the .java and class i need) and a x64 folder that contains opencv-300.dll

Comment: it's weird, that you never mention: `static{ System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }`

Comment: Into the tutorial it's not used and it work, i'm probably missing something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finaly solved my problem, the fact was that i called

```html
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

too late, so i moved it a bit and solved that :) Thanks for all who spend a bit of their time to help me there!

Comment: What do you mean by "moved it a bit"?  Above the call to `new Mat()` or did you have to move it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 Get dependency walker application.

Step 2 Browse into the relevant library folder.

Step 3 See what's missing and get it.

Tips:

Make sure You get DLL's for your architecture either 32bit or 64bit.

Make sure to compile with proper java (32bit/64bit) depending on which DLL's you provide.

Lastly if the dependencies you are missing start with MSVCP***.dll download  [Microsoft Visual C++ Packages](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40784). Again care for the architecture. I recommend you start with this step.

Comment: dependency walker told me some files were missing but i don't know what they even are :/
The thing that i can't understand is that on the tutorial i ran it on the library and it worked and on my project it don't.

Comment: install c++ visual packages for you architecture, 90% of the cases it solves the issue